# Selecting a menu item after hovering over a parent menu item using selenium

Tags: c#, python, .net, selenium, xpath

I want to select "Application Processing" menu item after I hover over the "Asmt Admin" parent menu item option. The html is as follows:

```
<div id="topmenu">
    <div id="ctl00_topMenu1" class="RadMenu RadMenu_GovernBlue rmSized">
        <ul class="rmRootGroup rmShadows rmHorizontal">
            <li class="rmItem">
                <a class="rmLink rmRootLink" href="#">
                    <span class="rmText rmExpandDown">Asmt Admin</span>
                </a>
                <div class="rmSlide">
                    <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel1">
                        <li class="rmItem ">
                            <a class="rmLink" href="#">
                                <span class="rmText">Application Processing</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('localhost:81'))

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
AsmtAdmin = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a/span[text()='Asmt Admin']")))
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(AsmtAdmin).perform()

ApplicationProcessing = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a/span[text()='Application Processing']")))
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(ApplicationProcessing).click().perform()
```

but the "Application Processing" menu item does not get clicked neither does the command line show any errors.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good to me but I will suggest 2 changes as follows:

1. As you are doing `browser.get(('localhost:81'))` and next doing `(By.XPATH, "//a/span[text()='Asmt Admin']")` I think you can omit the reference to `WebDriverWait`.
2. When searching for the element `(By.XPATH, "//a/span[text()='Application Processing']")` instead of `EC.visibility_of_element_located` you can use `EC.element_to_be_clickable`
3. Your final code will look like:

   ```
   AsmtAdmin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span[text()='Asmt Admin']")
   actions = ActionChains(browser)
   actions.move_to_element(AsmtAdmin).perform()
   ApplicationProcessing = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a/span[text()='Application Processing']"))
   )
   ApplicationProcessing.click()
   ```

Comment: I changed the code and I get the "Message: unknown error: Element <span class="rmText">...</span> is not clickable at point (204, 205). Other element would receive the click: <span class="rmText rmExpandRight">...</span>" error now

Comment: It seems the "application processing" link is not unique in the page. How do I ensure that the "application processing" link (that I am clicking) is a child of "Asmt Admin" parent menu?

Comment: Well, we can't control that. What best we can do is to construct a logical `xpath` or `css` which will always identify the node with text as `Application Processing` and once identified click on it.

Comment: Should not there be a way to "tie" the AsmtAdmin variable to the ApplicationProcessing variable to ensure that the correct menu item is clicked? Right now, the code does not have a way to tie the two together.

Comment: There may not be any tie if the Application is built with `AngularJS`

Comment: This is a normal ASP.NET application, the menu controls are rendered using Asp.Net telerik controls.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue using .Net and C#. We should be able to do something similar in Python. I believe, the important parts were using xpath for selecting the correct anchor tag and the enter key to click the anchor button.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System;

namespace AutomateQA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var usernameStr = "admin";
            var passwordStr = "admin";

            IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            chromeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            chromeDriver.Url = "http://localhost:81";

            var txtUserName = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserName"));
            txtUserName.SendKeys(usernameStr);

            var txtPassword = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword"));
            txtPassword.SendKeys(passwordStr);

            var btnLogin = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin"));
            btnLogin.Click();

            var asmtAdminElement = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Asmt Admin"));
            var actions = new Actions(chromeDriver);
            actions.MoveToElement(asmtAdminElement).Perform();

            var applicationProcessingSubElement = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Application Processing')]"));
            applicationProcessingSubElement.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        }
    }
}
```